# How can you run Instruments/Logger with a TestFlight app?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, instruments

If I try to run Instrument's logger for an app downloaded from TestFlight it says

"Permission to debug app name was denied".
"Recover Suggestion: The app must be debuggable and signed with 'get-task-allow'.

How do you make the app debuggable? (I tried creating an archive with the scheme set to Debug, but after uploading that to TestFlight, it doesn't appear. So presumably its not possible to upload an app built with debug scheme builds to TF?).
Therefore how can I make a TF build debuggable?, and how to sign it with get-task-allow?

Does it have to be a developer distribution .ipa rather than a TestFlight build to enable Instruments/Logger to run it?

Comment: You can't run Instruments with a testflight build. Use cmd-i in Xcode to create a profile build and launch instruments

Comment: But you can watch iOS `Logger` messages on the macOS Console app. E.g., as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589163/1271826) or under point 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951564/1271826). Or see WWDC 2020 video [Explore logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/). Note, depending upon what privacy settings you specified in your string interpolation, strings may not be visible. Also, this assumes you used a string for the `Logger` “category”, not `.pointsOfInterest`.